# Is there a form to convert a string to a decimal with two places

Tags: c#

I have this  tag in a XML

```
<seguroTotalReais>000000000037103</seguroTotalReais>
```

I need to set this value like a decimal with 2 places for example `371,03`.

Is there a way to do this without manipuling string directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of options, personally I would not do string operations on this. If you are looking to shift the decimal 2 places i would convert and then divide by 100. This will also give you some validation on whether its a numeric value or not.

```
string dec = "000000000037103";
// I did a string replace for swapping the dot to a comma.
Console.WriteLine((Convert.ToDouble(dec)/100).ToString("0.##").Replace(".",","));
```

You can also utilize Culture info to affect how your numbers are displayed as some culture info's utilize the comma as the decimal separator.

Comment: great that´s perfect for me i did not want to manipulate string